# Assign slider_value to variable in python

Tags: python, tkinter, slider

Okay, this is the code I am having problems with.

```
from guizero import App, Text, TextBox, PushButton, Slider, Picture

def change_number(slider_value):
    global



int_number
        int_number = slider_value
    str_number=str(int_number)

app = App(title="Hello World")

int_number=1
str_number=str(int_number)

picture = Picture(app, image= str_number+".gif")

update_image_number = Slider(app, command=change_number, start=1, end=3)

print_number = Text(app, text=str_number, size=15, font="Comic Sans", color="darkblue" )


app.display()
```

So as I have already said I am trying to use the Slider function to generate strings "1", "2" and "3", and  then concatenate them to ".gif" in order to change the image to be displayed depending on its name. However It is not working, but now I have no errors. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is. `int_number` is an integer, so you can't do `int_number(slilder_value)`. What are you trying to accomplish with that statement?Did you intend to do `int_number = slider_value`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried when I got the error. However it doesn't work or at least not the way I expected it to do it. So, I am trying to create a string "1", " 2" or "3" that changes in that range with the Slider utility. However it is not updating the string. Thanks a lot for your answer anyways!

Comment: I didn't give an answer, I was asking a question. What do you think `int_number(slider_value)` does? Are you trying to convert `slider_value` to an integer? Are you trying to set the value of `int_number`?

Comment: Oh sorry. Well I expected to assign the value of the Slider to the int_number. I do not have experience with python so probably I am missing something.